# Table Not Getting Refreshed After Deleting a Row

Tags: sapui5

[image]I am facing two issues when deleting a record in sap.m.Table as mentioned below.

1. After deleting a row using delete button, other rows are also getting vanished. Only after refreshing the page, I can see those records.

   [image: No data Page]
2. I have used success and error message after deleting the rows but it is not appearing.

*Table.view.xml*

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="sem.stock_app.controller.table"
>
  <Page
    title="Material Status"
    showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress="onNavBack"
  >
    <Table id="table"
      growing="true"
      mode="MultiSelect"
      items="{odata>np_on_matid}"
    >
      <columns>
        <Column>
          <CheckBox text="Select Entry"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Material ID"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Category"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Material Desc"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Plant"/>
        </Column>
      </columns>
      <items>
        <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="onPress">
          <CheckBox selected="{false}"/>
          <Text text="{odata>Matid}"/>
          <Text text="{odata>Category}"/>
          <Text text="{odata>Matdesc}"/>
          <Text text="{odata>Plant}"/>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
    </Table>
    <Button
      text="Delete"
      enabled="true"
      press="onDelete"
    />
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

*Table.Controller.js*

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/model/Filter",
  "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/m/MessageBox"
], function(Controller, JSONModel, Filter, History, MessageToast, MessageBox) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("sem.stock_app.controller.table", {
    onInit: function() {
      this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("r2").attachPatternMatched(this.mynav, this);
    },

    mynav: function(oeve) {
      var key = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("odata").createKey("matlistSet", {
        "Matid": oeve.getParameters().arguments.noti
      });
      this.getView().bindElement({
        path: "odata>/" + key,
        parameters: {
          expand: "np_on_matid"
        }
      });
    },

    onNavBack: function() {
      var oHistory = History.getInstance();
      var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
      if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
        window.history.go(-1);
      } else {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("r1", {}, true);
      }
    },

    onPress: function(oitem) {
      var x = oitem.getSource().getBindingContext("odata").getProperty("Matid");
      this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("r3", {
        matnr: x
      });
    },

    onDelete: function() {
      var i, tbl, aSelectedProducts, sPath, oProduct, oProductId;
      tbl = this.byId("table").getSelectedItems();
      aSelectedProducts = this.byId("table").getSelectedItems();
      if (aSelectedProducts.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < aSelectedProducts.length; i++) {
          oProduct = aSelectedProducts[i];
          oProductId = oProduct.getBindingContext("odata").getProperty("Matid");
          sPath = oProduct.getBindingContextPath();
          this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("odata").remove(sPath, {
            success: this._handleUnlistActionResult.bind(this, oProductId, true, i + 1, aSelectedProducts.length),
            error: this._handleUnlistActionResult.bind(this, oProductId, false, i + 1, aSelectedProducts.length)
          });
        }
      } else {
        this._showErrorMessage(this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("TableSelectProduct"));
      }
    },

    _handleUnlistActionResult: function(sProductId, bSuccess, iRequestNumber, iTotalRequests, oData, oResponse) {
      if (iRequestNumber === iTotalRequests) {
        MessageToast.show(this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("StockRemovedSuccessMsg", [iTotalRequests]));
      }
    },

  });
});
```

*Component.js*

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "sap/ui/Device",
  "sem/stock_app/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
  "use strict";

  return UIComponent.extend("sem.stock_app.Component", {
    metadata: {
      manifest: "json"
    },

    init: function() {
      var url = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMATLIST_SRV_03";
      var odata = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, {
        json: true
      });
      this.setModel(odata,"odata");
      UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.getRouter().initialize();
      this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser console? Also [sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel is out of maintenance](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014/) long time ago. Please, use [v2.ODataModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/) instead regardless of the behavior described in this question.

Comment: Thanks boghyon for your quick response. After changing the model now i can see the text after removing an item from table,so my second point is resolved. But still table is getting refreshed after deleting an item from table without any error in console. I have attached screenshot for your reference. Please let me know your input to fix this issue.

Comment: When a change is detected (e.g. removed an entry), a refresh (*GET*) request of the corresponding binding is bundled together with the former request and sent as a single batch request. In order to disable the automatic refresh, the [constructor parameter `refreshAfterChange`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/constructor) has to be set to `false`. However, if you have to disable that to fix the problem, it's an indication that something profound is not well designed in your application. Is batch operation implemented in your backend system in the first place?

Comment: Thanks a ton boghyon for your wonderful guide . I have implemented $batch operation at Odata level and the application is running fine as expected. Now issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issues were:

1. Use of `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` which has been out of maintenance [since long time ago](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014/)
2. There was no `$batch` operation implemented in the back-end system.